# How can I convert a Gradle project to be compiled offline without Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I've recently been working on building a spring boot application for a piece of university coursework using Gradle as my build tool of choice.

I write spring boot applications every day as a job using either maven or Gradle depending on client so I mistakenly went ahead and started development using Gradle without realizing that as part of the coursework specification the project had to be able to be compiled using the the default java compiler without any build tools. And also it has to be exported as a Netbeans project even though software should be IDE independent (but that's a side point). These requirements as backward as they may seem for producing enterprise applications are nonnegotiable.

So my question is whether there are any easy converters/plugins that will allow me to convert/export my Gradle project with all of its dependencies to a vanilla java project without having to manually download each dependency myself? To further clarify the only thing that I really care about is dependencies as I haven't made any custom tasks in the build file yet.

Obviously there is so much information on the web on how to convert vanilla to Gradle or Maven to Gradle that I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for through searches because the results get swamped.

If there isn't already a plugin I can use I may consider writing one for other people in the same situation as myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never going to get a gradle plugin which turns a `build.gradle` file into a vanilla javac execution. Gradle has so many features that it's pretty much impossible.

To help you on your way you could save the jars locally something like

```
task copyJars {
   doLast {
         copy {
             from configurations.compile
             into "$buildDir/jars/compile" 
         } 
         copy {
             from configurations.runtime.minus(configurations.compile)
             into "$buildDir/jars/runtime" 
         } 
         copy {
             from configurations.testCompile.minus(configurations.compile)
             into "$buildDir/jars/testCompile" 
         }      
         copy {
             from configurations.testRuntime.minus(configurations.testCompile).minus(configurations.runtime)
             into "$buildDir/jars/testRuntime" 
         }      
    } 
}
```

Comment: also should be the copyJars needs to be depend on `build` task?

Comment: Nope, I'm guessing you'll do this rarely and manually. So would explicitly invoke the task when needed. This task will be slow. You'll notice I didn't bother with task inputs/outputs either

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would do the trick. I'll wait a day or two and if nobody else has a better answer I'll mark you as the chosen answer.